# Why is 河原 in 河原町 pronounced "Kawara" as opposed to the expected "Kawabara/Kawawara"?

Tags: history

The Kawaramachi St in Kyoto is spelled with 河原, /kawa/ and /hara/. I'd suspect the two inner syllables to be merged into one mora at some point in history, but do we have a record of when that happened?

Further question: how old are the current street names and machi names in Kyoto generally?

Comment: "Expected" implies that the か and わら readings of these kanji are unusual or non-standard, but both are "nanori" (name) readings for them. You can find plenty of other names with those readings for those characters. E.g. 河西 (かさい), 藤原 (ふじわら)

Comment: That would beg the question, does this "ka" nanori have the same etymology as "kawa"?

Comment: For the record, there are more than 200 personal and place names where 河=か, excluding all 河原s, in Enamdict (a names dictionary). Examples include 美利河 Pirika, 河北郡 Kahokugun, 河根 Kane and many others.  They appear to me to include both cases where *ka* feels like a morpheme for "river", and others where 河 is clearly being used as an arbitrary pick of the syllable *ka* due to its nanori.

Comment: I think that is an entirely different situation. The "ka" in 河北郡, for example, seems to be the Kan'on from Middle Chinese /ɦɑ/ as opposed to a kun reading.

Comment: Oh, I missed that the *on* was also *ka*. But still, there are cases where *ka* feels like that, like 河北 (or maybe in kungana, like 下河渡頭 *shimokadogashira*), and others where it actually feels like "river", as in 河ヶ谷 *kagatani*, 河ノ畑 *kanohata*, or 蒲河浜 *kamagahama*.  The point is, there are  hundreds of personal and place names like that, and not just where one would expect an on-reading or phonetic (though there are those, too).

Answer (score 3):

かわら is a [normal noun](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B2%B3%E5%8E%9F) meaning "river beach". That is, when 河原 is used as a normal noun, it's always read as かわら at least in modern standard Japanese. (For example 河原を歩く, 河原できれいな石を見つけた.) That is the *expected* reading. [This 古語辞典](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AF%E3%82%89) suggests the word かわら existed at least 1000 years ago (except that it was written as かはら in the historical kana orthography).

As an *exception*, if 河原 is someone's family name or a place name, it may be read as かわはら or かわばら.